# Android:Cannot open file Not enough disk space

Tags: android, file, xml-parsing, memorycache

I have an application consist on reading AND saving an xml file and to write it if internet connection is available,else it will read the file already saved on the terminal.

WriteFeed function:

```
// Method to write the feed to the File
            private void WriteFeed(RSSFeed data) {

                FileOutputStream fOut = null;
                ObjectOutputStream osw = null;

                try {
                    fOut = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    osw = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);
                    osw.writeObject(data);
                    osw.flush();
                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally {
                    try {
                        fOut.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

WriteFeed function:

```
// Method to read the feed from the File
            private  RSSFeed ReadFeed(String fName) {

                FileInputStream fIn = null;
                ObjectInputStream isr = null;

                RSSFeed _feed = null;
                File feedFile = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fileName);
                if (!feedFile.exists())
                    return null;

                try {
                    fIn = openFileInput(fName);
                    isr = new ObjectInputStream(fIn);

                    _feed = (RSSFeed) isr.readObject();
                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally {
                    try {
                        fIn.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                return _feed;

            }
```

I have enough diskSpace ,sometimes i get "MemoryCach will use up to 16 Mb" ,always i get "Not enough disk space,will not index" and "FeatureCode > cannot open file"

whats wrong in my app?